# jQuery animate() not animating backgroundColor rgba

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a simple code and the structure is like this:

```
- div#imgholder
   - div#imgholderframe
      - div#bottombar
         - a
            - div#imgholderlogo
```

So there is a `div` in an `a` in a `div` in a `div` in a `div`, if that makes any sense.

What I want is that `div#imgholderframe`'s opacity changes in 600 ms as an animation when hovering over `div#imgholderlogo`

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kaj4C/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="imgholder">
    <div id="imgholderframe">
        <div id="bottombar">
            <a href="http://www.studio-2010.nl/" title="STUDIO 2010" target="_blank">
                <div id="imgholderlogo"></div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#imgholder {
    position:relative;
    width:960px;
    height:380px;
    overflow:hidden;
    background: url("http://s27.postimg.org/n2de00amb/bsl2.jpg") no-repeat;

}

#imgholderframe {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
    width:inherit;
    height:inherit;
}

#bottombar {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:55px;
}

#imgholderlogo {
   position:absolute; 
   background: url("http://s30.postimg.org/6weqohsrl/studio2010logo.jpg") no-repeat;
   background-size:100% 100%;
   margin-top:15px;
   width:258px;
   height:55.6px;
   right:0px;
   transition:margin-top .6s;
   opacity:1;
}

#imgholderlogo:hover {   
   margin-top:0px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#imgholderlogo").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().animate({backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.4)'},600);
});

$("#imgholderlogo").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().animate({backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0)'},600);
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kaj4C/)

Comment: you have not used jquery ui and you have background with images and you are changing white background with white background.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mathias is right [image]

https://api.jquery.com/animate/

You should use  jQuery.Color() plugin. Property values are treated as a number of pixels unless otherwise specified. The units em and % can be specified where applicable.

Comment: Great answer, made things clear. I learned something and now I'm working on a different animation instead.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery alone will not animate colors.

You can use jQuery UI or you can use native CSS transitions instead. You can use jQuery to add a class to your element and specify in your CSS that the background property should be animated.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions

Have a look here:

http://jsfiddle.net/7LZmW/

```
.box {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #0000FF;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 600ms;
    transition: background-color 600ms;
 }

 .box:hover {
    background-color: #FFCCCC;
 }
```

Comment: That's not right, here is a fiddle where it does happen. http://jsfiddle.net/2Dbrj/ For me it just doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @DaanHeskes jQuery without jQuery UI won't animate the colors.

Comment: Ok I guess I could have made it clear that jQuery UI will animate but jQuery alone won't. It is still a helpful solution, I hope.

Comment: That was my bad, didn't notice that was toggled on.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you have called background image to #imgholder and you want to change the opacity of div#imgholderframe. So I think, as div#imgholderframe is child of #imgholder, even if it is changing opacity end user can't see it. So try to change opacity of #imgholder (and you have written code in jquery to change background color which should not work).

you have to change opacity not background color of #imgholder. Please use below code:

```
$("#imgholderlogo").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().animate({"opacity": '0.4'},600);
});

$("#imgholderlogo").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().animate({"opacity": '1'},600);
});
```

this might work. Please put this code at the end of the page before `</body>` in script tag